# Instalando e importando o módulo Pygame no VSCode

Tags: python, pygame

Estou aprendendo a programar python através do VScode e encontrei dificuldades em importar o módulo pygame.

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load('nomedamusica.mp3')
pygame.mixer.music.play()
pygame.event.wait()
```

A mensagem que recebo é: 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame'

ja tentei instalar o módulo através do IDLE Python usando o

```
python -m pip install pygame
```

e deu Invalid Syntax

Qual caminho devo percorrer para instalar este módulo e qualquer outro módulo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você deve instalar o pacote via terminal e não no IDLE. Abra o terminal do seu sistema e digite o que você estava tentando:

```
python -m pip install pygame
```

Se diferentes versões do Python estão instaladas use `python` pra python 2 ou `python3`.